# Botão só envia dados do Gson para o TextView no Android 2.2

Tags: android

Boa noite!

Fiz o seguinte código para enviar os dados de um WebService Json para um TextView a partir de um botão:

```
package br.edu.ipesu.thermostop;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button botaoTemperatura;
    TextView resultadoTemperatura;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        botaoTemperatura = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoTemperatura);
        botaoTemperatura.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener)this);
        resultadoTemperatura = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultadoTemperatura);
        resultadoTemperatura.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener)this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId()==R.id.botaoTemperatura){


            try {
                String name = "30%20Graus";
                String url = "http://117.193.26.104:8080/WelcomeRESTJSON/" + "resources/welcome/" + name ;

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader (new URL(url).openStream());
                TextMessage message = new Gson().fromJson(reader, TextMessage.class);
                resultadoTemperatura.setText(message.getMessage().toString());

            }
            catch (Exception exception) {
                resultadoTemperatura.setText("Erro!");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    class TextMessage {
        private String message;

        public String getMessage(){
            return message;
        }
        public void setMessage(String value){
            message = value;
        }
    }
}
```

O código roda perfeitamente quando testado no Android 2.2, mas nas versões 4.2 em diante o mesmo pula para o catch exception. Qual seria o problema?

PS: Adicionei o LogCat ao clicar no botão abaixo:

```
09-27 02:25:37.530: W/System.err(1201): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-27 02:25:37.579: W/System.err(1201):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
09-27 02:25:37.579: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
09-27 02:25:37.663: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
09-27 02:25:37.663: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
09-27 02:25:37.669: W/System.err(1201):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-27 02:25:37.683: W/System.err(1201):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
09-27 02:25:37.683: W/System.err(1201):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
09-27 02:25:37.689: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
09-27 02:25:37.701: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
09-27 02:25:37.701: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
09-27 02:25:37.701: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
09-27 02:25:37.722: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
09-27 02:25:37.729: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
09-27 02:25:37.750: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
09-27 02:25:37.761: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
09-27 02:25:37.761: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
09-27 02:25:37.761: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
09-27 02:25:37.761: W/System.err(1201):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
09-27 02:25:37.769: W/System.err(1201):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
09-27 02:25:37.800: W/System.err(1201):     at br.edu.ipesu.thermostop.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
09-27 02:25:37.800: W/System.err(1201):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-27 02:25:37.800: W/System.err(1201):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-27 02:25:37.819: W/System.err(1201):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-27 02:25:37.819: W/System.err(1201):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-27 02:25:37.819: W/System.err(1201):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 02:25:37.849: W/System.err(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-27 02:25:37.849: W/System.err(1201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 02:25:37.849: W/System.err(1201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 02:25:37.861: W/System.err(1201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-27 02:25:37.861: W/System.err(1201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-27 02:25:37.861: W/System.err(1201):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

RESOLVIDO! Usei uma AsyncTask, onde as linhas do InputStreamReader e TextMessage ficaram no doInBackground retornando null e o setText do TextView ficou no onPostExecute.

Comment: poderia postar a exception? ajudaria a te ajudar!

Comment: Só por curiosidade, porque você adiciona o OnClickListener no Textview?

Comment: Implementei o OnClickListener na class MainActivity e fiz que onClick(View v) modifique o TextView ao clicar no botão. Está funcionando pois já testei o try sem a linha InputStreamReader e mandar uma String qualquer no setText do TextView. Pelo que estou vendo está ocorrendo uma excessão no InputStreamReader quando roda no Android 4.2 ou superior (ele pula pro catch exception e executa o setText dele com a frase "Erro!". Estou pesquisando uma outra alternativa de usar InputStreamReader para carregar a url em JSON mas tá difícil.

OBS: Estou usando o Eclipse que vem com o ADT 20130729.

Comment: e o exception.printStackTrace(); mostra algo no  log cat? Faça o seguinte:   modifique  a seguinte linha resultadoTemperatura.setText("Erro!"); PARA: resultadoTemperatura.setText(exception.getMessage()); e poste aqui par sabermos exatamente o erro!

Comment: Ao fazer isto não mostra nada na tela. Aqui está o logCat quando clica no botão: http://notepad.cc/share/jcsEJaQpZO

Comment: OSB: O android.permission.INTERNET (Uses Permission) está no AndroidManifest.xml.